# How to fix: 'Failed to connect to (URL) from port() after 10000ms'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, async-await

I am building a React Native application and i've come across a problem with downloading some images. Problem is that after several successfully downloaded images I come across and error saying

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: failed to connect to javatrade.maniatest.win/ip-adress] from /10.0.3.15 after 10000ms.

I thought the problem came from my code, I've tried recording it several times but the problem still persists.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        downloadImages: [],
        arrLength: 0,
        progress: 0
    };
}

componentWillMount = async() => {
    axios.post('apilink')
        .then(async (response) => {
            await this.setState({ downloadImages: response.data.images, arrLength: response.data.images.length });
        })
        .finally(async() => {
            this.startDownloading();
        })
}

startDownloading = async() => {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.state.downloadImages.length; i++){
        await this.processArray(this.state.downloadImages[i])
    }

    console.log('Finished');
}

processArray = async(el) => {
    const { progress, arrLength } = this.state;
    this.setState({ progress: progress + (1/arrLength) });
    await new Promise(async(resolve) => {
        const name = el.split('/').pop();
        const imageInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(`${FileSystem.documentDirectory}allImages/files/${name}`);
        if(imageInfo.exists) {
            console.log('Already exists');
            return resolve();
        } else {
            await FileSystem.downloadAsync(el, `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}allImages/files/${name}`);
            console.log('Finished downloading');
            return resolve();
        }
    })
}
```

So I expect from this component to download images from the provided links from the API ( there are around 50 of them ). Sometimes I download 3 then the Promise error occurs, sometimes I download 12 and Promise errors occurs I am not sure what am I doing wrong?

Here is the picture link of the error from the console.log.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq5lJ.png